# \underbrace problem with newtxsf package on MiKTeX

Tags: amsmath, newtx, underbrace

the following simple example delivers a broken underbrace symbol on my machine. Same goes for overbrace. Any Ideas how to solve the issue or work around? I run on Win10 and MiKTeX / TeXworks with updated packages and all installed updates.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm, varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{80px}{80px}\selectfont
$\underbrace{n \cdot n \cdot n}_{n}= \Omega$
\end{document}
```

[image: \underbrace command with newtxsf]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It looks like you've come across a bug in the `newtxsf` package. Have you contacted the package's maintainer? The package's maintainer is known to be very responsive to and diligent about fixing bug reports. (Contact information is provided on the first page of the package's user guide.) TeX.SE is not particularly well suitd for bug reports.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I reported the issue to the maintainer. The workarounds from egreg were also very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newtxsf` package redefines `\upbracefill` and `\downbracefill` to use a glyph instead of filling the braces with a rule, as happens in standard LaTeX. Unfortunately, this glyph *doesn't* exist at all (and you find `Missing character` warnings in your log file).

First workaround: keep the original definitions.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % avoid a spurious warning
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oriupbracefill\upbracefill
\let\oridownbracefill\downbracefill

\usepackage{newtxsf}

\let\upbracefill\oriupbracefill
\let\downbracefill\oridownbracefill

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{n \cdot n \cdot n}_{n}=\overbrace{n\cdot n\cdot n}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second workaround: uncomment a line in `newtxsf.sty`.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % avoid a spurious warning
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxsf}

\makeatletter
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\br@cext}{\mathord}{largesymbolsTXA}{32}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{n \cdot n \cdot n}_{n}=\overbrace{n\cdot n\cdot n}$
\end{document}
```

[image]